# Import Image into Eclipse Plugin

Tags: swt, eclipse-plugin

I have developed an eclipse Plugin using Java SWT. My plugin has few Wizard Pages.
Now, I need to add an image/logo on the header part of the Wizard Pages.
Can anyone give suggestions on how to do the same using SWT please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images in a plugin are usually placed in an `images` or `icons` folder - don't forget to add this folder to the `build.properties` so that it will be included in the built plugin.

You load images from the folder using:

```java
final URL fullPathString = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);

ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(fullPathString);

Image image = imageDesc.createImage();
```

`bundle` is your plugin `Bundle`, you can get this from your Activator (if you have one) or using:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

or

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

`path` is the image path relative to the plugin - so something like `images/xxx.gif`

If you create an `Image` you must dispose of it when done (`ImageDescriptor` does not need to be disposed).

You can use `org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry` to manage the images and image descriptors.

Update:

Once you have an `ImageDescriptor` you set it as the title image on a wizard page by calling `WizardPage.setImageDescriptor(descriptor)`.

Comment: thanks... :) i will try this one. But not sure if this image would appear in my plugin's header.

Comment: Added usage in WizardPage

Comment: hi I couldn't get with this **path** variable.Can you please give me an example. the documentation shows something like Path path = new Path(Device device), i couldn't understand that one.

Comment: Sounds like you have the wrong Path import, the correct one is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path`